# Issues with Ionic Zip looping through a list of .pngs and converting file names to a streamReader and replacing old .png file names in a .js file

Tags: c#, ionic-framework, c#-ziparchive

Thanks guys for the previous answers. I am now having a new issue with my code while looping through a list of .png graphics and then converting those file names to a streamReader string that replaces the old .png file names in a .js file.

I know there has to be a better way of doing this. Do you guys have any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong or examples that could help me out?

The following code works as it should for the .png file names.

```
using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(filePath))
        {
            var zipEntryPng = (from e in zip.Entries
                               where (e.FileName).EndsWith(".png")
                               select e).ToList();

            foreach (ZipEntry entry in zipEntryPng)
            {
                entry.FileName = Regex.Replace(entry.FileName.Trim(), @"[^\w@-]", "");
                entry.FileName = entry.FileName.Remove(entry.FileName.Length - 3);
                entry.FileName = entry.FileName.Insert(6, "/");
                entry.FileName = entry.FileName + ".png";                                          
            }
            zip.Save();
        }
```

This is the new code that I'm having issues with. I know that it definitely has something to do with the zip file operations of removing the entry, adding the new entry and saving it in the foreach loop. It cycles through all .png files and writes all of the new file names in the .js file except the last one. So it is exiting the loop before it gets to the last .png file.

Below is the new code that I'm talking about:

```
  foreach (ZipEntry entry in zipEntryPng)
            {
                var oldFileName = entry.FileName;
                var zipEntryJs = zip.Entries.FirstOrDefault(z => z.FileName.EndsWith(".js"));

                entry.FileName = Regex.Replace(entry.FileName.Trim(), @"[^\w@-]", "");
                entry.FileName = entry.FileName.Remove(entry.FileName.Length - 3);
                entry.FileName = entry.FileName.Insert(6, "/");
                entry.FileName = entry.FileName + ".png";

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    zipEntryJs.Extract(ms);
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.Default))
                    {
                        ms.Position = 0;
                        textStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        textStr = textStr.Replace(oldFileName, entry.FileName);
                    }
                    ms.Flush();
                    ms.Close();
                }

                zipEntryJs.FileName = Regex.Replace(zipEntryJs.FileName.Trim(), @"[^\w@-]", "");
                zipEntryJs.FileName.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
                zipEntryJs.FileName = zipEntryJs.FileName.Remove(zipEntryJs.FileName.Length - 2);
                zipEntryJs.FileName = zipEntryJs.FileName + ".js";
                zip.RemoveEntry(zipEntryJs);
                zip.AddEntry(zipEntryJs.FileName, textStr);
                zip.Save();
            }
            zip.Save();
        }
```

Comment: Try either putting a `ToList` after your query or maybe move the `zip.Save()` out of the `foreach` loop.  I'm guessing that saving while having an open enumeration on the entries might be throwing it off.

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: Thanks guys. Wael, I did not receive an error at all. I added a .ToList() after my query and moved the zip.Save() out of the loop as Juharr suggested and it worked for me.

Comment: I tried using an array to add the file names to and used the StreamReader outside of the using statement with no avail. There has got to be a better way to do this.